# How to download sharepoint files in databricks

Tags: sharepoint, databricks

How to download sharepoint files in databriks. Tried differnet approaches still unable to authenticate & download...

Comment: What have you tried ? Please read [ask] for understand how to write good questions. I have no knowledge of what is databricks, but in general, you have to setup azure ad application to get appid/appsecret, ask an admin to consent the application and use one the oauth auth flow (assuming SharePoint online, it rather different if onprem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reading data from sharepoint using Azure databricks is not possible. Sharepoint is not supported source in Azure databricks.**

For more details, kindly refer to [Azure Databricks - Datasources.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/)

I found a third party articles which explains - [Process & Analyze SharePoint Data in Azure Databricks](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sharepoint-jdbc-azure-databricks.rst).

Here are steps:

1. Install the CData JDBC Driver in Azure
2. Connect to SharePoint from Databricks

   (1) Configure the Connection to SharePoint
   (2) Built-in Connection String Designer
   (3) Load SharePoint Data
3. Analyze SharePoint Data in Azure Databricks

Comment: The answer is unclear: the first sentence says we can't access data from Sharepoint, and the remaining paragraph says the opposite.